# What do we call a small grin?

Tags: word-request

Grin is to smile from ear to ear (widely).  Please let me know the word which is used to define a little grin?

If this is Grin,
[image]

then what do we call this?

[image]

Comment: From the pictures, I think you are looking for **smirk** or **simper**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you've answered your own question. It is perfectly acceptable to use the term "little grin" to describe a little grin. The word "smirk," while often a smaller smile, implies conceit or smugness. It may or may not be the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not wide grins may also be described as *faint, feeble, slight, shy, lazy,* *rueful* (like the grin in photo 2; it also might be called "a knowing grin").

The broad grin in photo one I'd call *a smug or complacent grin*.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in your answer.

Comment: @AhmbroDude - Where? I can't spot it.

Comment: @rompay - It should be "note" instead of "not". Am I right?

Comment: I meant "not wide" as a near synonym for "small/not large"

Comment: Feel free to edit if it helps you with your question;)